# cppcheck: Syntax error with using/typedef

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I have a syntax error with cppcheck and using/typedef declarations.
I have a struct that contains

```
struct inferior
{

    using visitor = int;

    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T &a, const T &b) const
    {
        return a < b;
    }
};

int main() { 
    return 0; 
}
```

when I run `cppcheck file.cpp` output is

`[file.cpp:5]: (error) syntax error` with no further output.

The error  disappeared if I remove the `using` declaration.

I wonder if it's normal behaviour from `cppcheck`. the `using`  declaration not being used directly. (It's a reduced example with a `using` redefining int).

Some context if needed: In my application, the `using` defines a specialisation of a visitor `OnlyArithmetic` like so: `using visitor = OnlyArithmetic<inferior>` that filters the non-arithmetic types using metaprogramming techniques, then I call std::visit on inferior::visitor(). I used this trick to not repeat the filtering part for all structures I need (inferior, superior, ...).

[EDIT] Using cppcheck 1.88

Comment: try adding `--std=c++11` to the command line, I don't know what cppcheck is using by default

Comment: A quick look at cppcheck's forum suggests that a bug has crept in recently; there are  other reports about false syntax errors. If you have a recent version, I would try rolling back a bit.

Comment: What version of cppcheck?

Comment: Thanks for you reply I tried with `--std=c++11` but same behaviour. I was using cppcheck 1.88 (latest homebrew formula). I built cppcheck from sources (1.89) but same problem but with a bit more output. I then downgraded to 1.76.1 (one of their [branches](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/)) and problem disappeared

Answer (score 0):

As *molbdnilo* suggested. Problem disappeared with [cppcheck release 1.85](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/releases/tag/1.85).

Answer (score 0):

This issue was introduced with Cppcheck 1.86 and was fixed in version 1.89.